# Float getting truncated in teradata sql

Tags: sql, teradata

Teradata Float datatype truncates decimal value to 2 decimal point.

```
select cast(10.123456789 as float) deci_num
```

Answer:

> deci_num
>
> 10.12

Could anyone please tell me how to avoid this **without converting to Decimal or Double** because i have a table with float column which is storing only truncated value ?

Its working in Oracle but not in Teradata. Why ?

Comment: works for me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/20922

Comment: @juergend : Its not working in Teradata. Please see the question header

Comment: Why did you then tag as [oracle]?

Comment: @juergend : Its working in oracle.. oracle users may know the reason

Comment: @juergend : I found the answer myself. Please see. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its just setting need to be changed in teradata.

```
Tools --> Options --> Answerset --> No.of Decimal Points to display for float --> <set as you want>
```

Now getting as below

> deci_num
>
> 10.1234567890